# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "proj" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Student"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

suddenly my route started showing me this error, I don't know whats wrong with it. 
I am trying to pass the id from the middleware. and use it to fetch the document.
I made a field name hostId where I store the id of the user who has created the project in the string form.

The error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "proj" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Student"
    at model.Query.exec (D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4545:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4644:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"proj"',
      at ObjectId.cast (D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:245:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1135:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1567:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1557:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1534:20)
      at cast (D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:336:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4968:12)
      at model.Query.Query._castConditions (D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2056:10)
      at model.Query.<anonymous> (D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2335:8)
      at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:27:8)
      at D:\KabirProject\FindAlly\node_modules\kareem\index.js:370:33
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11),
  valueType: 'string'
```

Here's my route:

```
router.get('/student/projects', signin,(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const id = req.user._id
        const Projects =  PersonalProject.find({hostId: id});
        const user = req.user;
        res.render("student/myProjects", {Projects, user});
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Signin middleware:

```
function signin(req, res, next){
    const {cookies} = req;
    if(!cookies){
        return res.status(401).json({error:"You must be signed in"})

    }
  
    const token = cookies.jwtToken.replace("Bearer ","")
    jwt.verify(token,process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,(error,user)=>{
        if(error){
            return res.status(401).json({error: "You must be signed in"})
        }
        req.user = user;
        console.log(user._id)
        next();
    });
}
```

personal Project Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const personalProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [2, "Length of your name is too short"],
        maxlength: [50, "Max length reached"]

    },
    host:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: [2, "field length is too short"],
        maxlength: [50, "Max length reached"]
    },
    hostId:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    year:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [2, "Length of your name is too short"],
        maxlength: [30, "Max length reached"]
    },
    branch:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [2, "Length of your name is too short"],
        maxlength: [50, "Max length reached"]
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required: true,
        trim:true
    },
    role:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [2, "Length of your name is too short"],
        maxlength: [15, "Max length reached"]
        
    },
    status:{
        type: String,
        default: "ACTIVE",
        required: true
    },
    githubLink:{
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    teamLimit:{
        type: Number,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    teammates:[]
    
},
{timestamps:true}

);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', personalProjectSchema);
```

Student Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [2, "Length of your name is too short"],
        maxlength: [50, "Max length reached"]

    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
        
    },
    gender:{
        type:String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [4, "Length of your name is too short"],
        maxlength: [6, "Max length reached"]
    },
    year:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [2, "Length of your name is too short"],
        maxlength: [30, "Max length reached"]
    },
    branch:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [2, "Length of your name is too short"],
        maxlength: [50, "Max length reached"]
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    mobNo:{
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        minlength: [10, "Length of your name is too short"],
        maxlength: [10, "Max length reached"]
    },
    role:{
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        minlength: [2, "Length of your name is too short"],
        maxlength: [15, "Max length reached"]
    }

},
{timestamps: true}
);

mongoose.model("Student", studentSchema);
```

please help me find the problem.

Comment: Error says problem in `Student` model, but you have added code `Project` model

Comment: @ArifKhan Sorry, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a Cast error, it means that you need to use smth like this:
`Schema.Types.ObjectId(_id)`
to convert your value to ObjectId type.
Second, it looks like you have a problem in other part of your code(not one that you provided), check where are you using aggregation with Student model and convert _id prop to ObjectId type